# Why is Play! breaking apart the {format} param in routes?

Tags: scala, playframework

Must be a syntax issue on my part, but can't quite pin it:

In my controller I have this defined:

```
request.format match {
      case "json" => Json(output)
      case "xml" => toXml(parse(output.toString))
      case _   => BadRequest
    }
```

And in my routes I have this defined:

```
# Map the API to the proper domain
GET     /{key}/{action}/{param}.{format}    API.{action}
POST    /{key}/{action}/{param}.{format}    API.{action}
```

I posted something like: `/34523452345/job/today.json`

So when I go to actually run the request, it takes {param} and includes the period. So the result for {param} is `today.js` and the {format} becomes `on`

**The catch** if I switch the period to a forward slash `/` it works just fine

What is the cause of the problem?

Comment: have you tried to escape the dot? \.

Comment: I think @PereVillega is on to something. If they use regex, then `.` stands for any character.

Comment: that worked beautifully! @PereVillega post that as an answer and i'll accept it right away. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have to escape the dot as in `\.`, as Play uses regexp in the `routes` files.